# модуль экспорта каталог в pdf видает ошибку

Tags: opencart

Здравствуйте установил модуль экспорта каталог в pdf, при экспорте выдает ошибку.

```
Notice: Undefined index: image in /home/selfy/selfy.com.ua/www/admin/controller/module/topdf.php on line 2892
Notice: Undefined index: manufacturer in /home/selfy/selfy.com.ua/www/admin/controller/module/topdf.php on line 2936
Notice: Undefined index: name in /home/selfy/selfy.com.ua/www/admin/controller/module/topdf.php on line 2967
Notice: Undefined index: description in /home/selfy/selfy.com.ua/www/admin/controller/module/topdf.php on line 2985
Notice: Undefined index: price in /home/selfy/selfy.com.ua/www/admin/controller/module/topdf.php on line 3027
Notice: Undefined index: tax_class_id in /home/selfy/selfy.com.ua/www/admin/controller/module/topdf.php on line 3027
Notice: Undefined index: special in /home/selfy/selfy.com.ua/www/admin/controller/module/topdf.php on line 3036
```

Строка ошибки

```
   $image=$mas_prod['image'];
```

стоит  ocStore 2.1.0.2.1

Comment: Кэш модификаторов чистили, версия модуля соответствует? Что за модуль?

Comment: Имя модуля export_pdf_v8_oc20  да версия подходит, кеш чистил

Comment: Как чистили кеш? Через админку или убивали в папке? $mas_prod - где формируется покажите.

Comment: через админку. ссилка на файлb где формируется selfy.com.ua/topdf.rar